# Ctrl+alt+down arrow key not working in eclipse juno

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using eclipse Juno and i am having shortcut problem .I have searched a lot for no result  .Guys u are my last hope.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd>+ <kbd>down arrow</kbd> = will give the copy of line  in which you  currently are. 
  but instead of this it is rotating my screen .what to do  plz help

Thanx in advance

Comment: Works ok for me without no tweaking. Sounds like you have installed some display controller software that captures that combination... does all the display rotate (including OS bars, menus, etcs.) or just the eclipse content?

Comment: all the things are rotating

Comment: problem solved...If any one having this problem  then here is the solution for this .
go to the graphics property after that hot key options : you will find an check box to enable to hot keys .uncheck that option and click apply and ok ..and you are done

Comment: If you use xubuntu the solution is this: run xfwm4-settings open tab Keyboard. There you will find a key binding for Ctrl-Alt-up and Ctrl-Alt-Down for switching to the upper desktop or lower desktop. Clear those key bindings and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's windows that's turning your screen around. See [this page](http://engtech.wordpress.com/2006/08/01/stupid-windows-features-monitor-display-turns-sideways-or-upside-down/) for information on how to fix that. If that doesn't work, you could also change the binding for the command in preferences > general > keys

Comment: The Commands to look for in Eclipse are `Copy Lines` (paste below) and `Duplicate Lines` (paste above).

Answer (score 12):

If anyone is having this problem, then the solution for it might look like this:

Go to the graphics property (right mouse click on Desktop). After that, find and deselect the "hot keys enabled" option (for ATI: graphics property > preferences > hotkeys...).

Comment: Where is the "graphics property" you are talking about?

Comment: @Pacerier right mouse click on desktop,it sits in the context menu list.